# Taking user input from a button in `Manipulate`?

Tags: manipulate, input

The following code is intended to display one image from a list of images, and `Export` the selected image to a file when the "Save" button is activated:

```
viewer[imgList_?(VectorQ[#, ImageQ] &)] := 
 Manipulate[imgList[[frame]], {{frame, 1}, 1, Length@imgList, 1},
  Row[{Button["Save", 
     Export[SystemDialogInput[
       "FileSave", {"", {".tif" -> {"*.tif"}}}], imgList[[frame]]]]}]]
```

But the `SystemDialogInput` complains when run from inside `Manipulate`:

> SystemDialogInput::nprmtv: SystemDialogInput is not currently
>   supported within preemptive evaluations. >>

Does anyone know a workaround to let the user select a file name at runtime with `Manipulate`?

Comment: @unlikely `SynchronousUpdating` -> True, False, and Automatic all give the same result.

Answer (score 2):

From [`Button`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Button.html) documentation:

> By default, button functions are evaluated on a preemptive link and time out after 5 seconds
>
> Use `Method->"Queued"` to evaluate button functions on the main link, which never times out:

So try something like this:

```
Manipulate[
 file,
 {{file, file}, None},
 Button["...", file = SystemDialogInput["FileSave"], 
  Method -> "Queued"]]
```